# Algorithm to solve inheritance from relationships

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics

I have a graph which nodes are related together with 2 relationships:
`subclassOf`, `partOf`.

There are some nodes with some properties. If B is `subclassOf` A then B inherits A's properties and if D is `partOf` C then C inherits D's properties.

I have tried some algorithm to inference all nodes properties but my program hanged.

Can any algorithm (brute force) do this?

Comment: Is hasVulnerability a property of a node or do you mean that for two nodes A and B we have an edge A->B if A hasVulnerability regarding B?

Comment: we have some nodes with 2 edge is subclassof and ispartof.each node may have some property. when we go through the graphprogram must infer the property for the other node due to the edg.when B is subclass of A it must inherits its property and when C is part of B it then B must get the C property.

Comment: Can C be a sublassOf both A and B?  Can C be partOf both A and B?

Comment: @mbeckish no one node can not be subclass of 2 node

Comment: @Persian - What about partOf?  Can one node be partOf 2 nodes?

Comment: So you basically want a transitive closure of a Directed Acyclic Graph?

Comment: @mbeckish yes one node can be part of tow nodes or more.

Comment: @ Parakram Majumdar each parent must give it's property to child and each part give it's property to the whole in part-whole relationship

Answer (score 0):

Lets say class B inherits from A and class C inherits from B, so class C actually inherits from A too.

```
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();

        if (b is A)
        {
            //True
        }
        if (c is B)
        {
            //True
        }
        if (c is A)
        {
            //True
        }
        if (a is B)
        {
            //False
        }
        A a1 = b as A;
        if (a1 != null)
        {
            //So a1 is b
        }
```

Comment: if D is part of A and D has some vulnerabilities then A must inherit D's vulnerabilities too.so what should do for this?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what is vulnerabilities, do you mean Fields, Properties. Methods?

Comment: it is a property.when B is subclass of A it must inherits its property and when C is part of B it then B must get the C property.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Directed Acyclic Graph [( DAG )](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), since if B is a `subClassOf`A : `A->B`, then A is `not subClassOf` B or of any class that is in turn `subClassOf` B. The same rule applies to `partOf` property as well (D is `partOf` C : `D->C` ). This implies that there's no cyclic dependency between the classes.

BTW, in an OOP world the `partOf` relation doesn't imply inheritance at all. So normally if D `isPartOf` C, C doesn't get D's properties. It can be made to get it, using something like an [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), but by default C `encapsulates` D is all is implied.

If you're writing a query function that returns all the properties of a class `C` like you want, you can use recursion and get it. The recursion will terminate since this is a DAG. If, by mistake, there're cycles in your relationship graph, the recursion will stack overflow. Pseudo code follows.

```
Properties propertyOf(c) {
    Properties p = c.localProperties; //Init to props defined specific to `C`
    foreach (var edge in edges(c)){
        if(dest(edge) == c){ //Only interested in `inflowing` edges.
            if( type(edge) == "subClassOf" || type(edge) == "partOf"){
                p.append( propertyOf ( source(edge) ) ) //Recurse further into source nodes
            }
        }        
    }
    return p
}
```

Comment: but in sub class edge parent give it's property to child and in it's part of it is opposite and child give it's property to the whole(part-whole edge)